GraphDB File Import UI Bug
When I try to import an RDF file through the import user data tab in the UI, I get a bug, and I'm unable to select any option for uploading, see screenshot. It worked in Firefox at one point.
I've tried in several browsers (Firefox, Chrome, Edge, Safari) and see the same issue. How do I solve this?import bug screenshot
I should see several separate options (not overlapping text blob) and then an upload/browse for file box.

The issue with the UI comes from the Popover api introduced in the Chromium on which both Chrome and Edge are based.
Currently the easiest way to fix the issue is to update your GraphDB to at least 10.4.1.
